# mongodb fetch batch wise records

Tags: java, mongodb, rest

I have a requirement to export 500k mongo db records as a csv file via java rest api.
All is well until I don't talk about performance.
I would like to know if there is a optimal way to fetch half a million  or one million records from mongodb  without making the kubernetes pod crash. currently my pod size is just 2GB.
Is there any way to optimally fetch huge amount of records from mongoDB and then export it as a file when user hits the rest API?

I have a working solution now where I am doing **find all** records in mongoDB and then constructing a csv file and then exporting the csv file.  But I would like to know if there is any better way to do it?

Comment: Using Indian words like "lac" isn't going to help getting others to understand your issue.

Comment: got it..will update :)/ thanks